# custom php.ini / php_value : which takes precedence?

Tags: php, apache-config

We could override the default php.ini settings using the

`PHPINIDir /var/www/web1`

directive in `<VirtualHost>` decription.

But I have seen `php_value` statements which is applied to all the sites in  the httpd.conf files. For example :

`php_value upload_max_filesize somevalue`

Will the general settings like above override the custom php.ini settings?

Pardon me that I don't have an environment to test this out at present.

Comment: changed the title to custom php.ini

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHP configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) precedence order is as follows:

1. The php.ini
2. The conf.d directory. On some distros, there is a modularized conf.d directory. values specified in there override php.ini
3. The directive PHPINIDir /var/www/web1 replaces 1 and 2 with your custom php.ini
4. Apache virtual host configuration. e.g. "php_value error_reporting " overrides any php.ini
5. .htaccess files placed inside your webspace override the above configuration
6. Source code values specified in the source code override all other configuration

[Some (security critical) options can only be set in higher level config files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Comment: Cheers mate !! nicely summarized .

Comment: First, the link is broken. I get a blank page when I click it. Second, could you cite relevant documentation for your assertion here: "Configuration options 5 and 6 may be disabled in php.ini" -- How do I do this?

Comment: @void.pointer I fixed the link - I did not find a very good replacement, though.