# PHP Memory Limit - using less memory than the limit, but still error occurs

Tags: php, memory-limit

I have a strange memory limit issue in PHP. I have to read a lot of data into an array using a particular script, and I keep running out of memory.

My memory is now at 2048M in the `php.ini` file, and `phpinfo()` indicates it as such, yet, I keep getting this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 142610432 bytes) in ... on line 173`

Now - those two total about 680MB. This is far below the limit I set it to. Why would this error still occur?

Comment: Do you have some flag in your `.htaccess` for example `php_value memory_limit 512M` ?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file.  Both master and local value in phpinfo() shows 2048MB. My server has 32GB of RAM with otherwise < 5% utilization, so it is also not a memory shortage on the server.

Comment: Did you try setting it with `ini_set("memory_limit" , "2048M");` in most cases this will overwrite all other configuration. Is that what you mean with `in the config file`

Comment: I just tried the init_set() you suggested, and it works, so then the question becomes "why?" Thank you, regardless, issue is solved for me, and no, the config file I meant php.ini file.

Comment: You can view how PHP Configuration is biuld in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33933470/3768239

Comment: Thank you for the above link - very insightful - but if I run `phpinfo()` it means only the script (last option) would be different, not true? The phpinfo() indicated 2048M in both master and local value.

Comment: Just out of interest, compared to the `phpinfo()`, what does `ini_get('memory_limit')` return?

Comment: Very interesting, Patrick. ini_get('memory_limit') says 512MB... Quite strange.

Comment: Is this script run via CLI or via webserver?

Comment: In my browser window - so not CLI. Very good question, as there are separate configs for CLI and non-CLI, right?

Comment: Yep, two different `php.ini`s for CLI and webserver. `phpinfo()` should tell you which one it uses

Comment: Not using cli I think. `return php_sapi_name() === 'cli'` evaluates to false.

Comment: As it seems that `phpinfo()` isn't totally telling us the correct value, I would try and search recursively in all config files below `/etc` with a tool such as `rg` (ripgrep). You could do `cd /etc` and then simply `rg memory_limit`. You might have to do it under your document root also.

Comment: Might be a different (user) file being read. Maybe try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php to see which ones got loaded. How do you serve? Apache? Nginx? PHP server?

Comment: `print_r(php_ini_scanned_files())` is empty. Good suggestion. Thanks! Using Apache.

Comment: @angel.bonev - will you post as answer? Your comment got my functionality to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration
> option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and
> will be restored at the script's ending.

```
ini_set("memory_limit" , "2048M");
```

In most cases **ini_set** rewrites all other PHP configurations